# table of common elements between samples

Tags: r

I have 6 differents vectors with name stored in them.
I want to display a table with, as column and row each vector, the intersection being the number of element common in each of them.

for exemple as input:

```
a <- c('tom','john','phil')  
b <- c('phil','leo','james')  
d <- c('tom','john', 'dan')
```

Output:

```
  a  b  d  
a 3     
b 1  3 
d 2  0  3
```

with in each cell `sum(rowname %in% colname)`

Is there a way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be an overkill, but should work reasonably fast with large data.

Steps are:

1. Generate a document feature matrix with `quanteda`
2. Conduct matrix multiplication

```
library(quanteda)
library(dplyr)
a <- c('tom','john','phil')  
b <- c('phil','leo','james')  
d <- c('tom','john', 'dan')

feature_matrix <- list(a, b, d) %>% as.tokens %>% dfm
feature_matrix
#> Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 6 features (50.0% sparse).
#>        features
#> docs    tom john phil leo james dan
#>   text1   1    1    1   0     0   0
#>   text2   0    0    1   1     1   0
#>   text3   1    1    0   0     0   1
feature_matrix %*% t(feature_matrix)
#> 3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#>       text1 text2 text3
#> text1     3     1     2
#> text2     1     3     .
#> text3     2     .     3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

A last step to get the exact same result would be:

```
library(Matrix)
feature_matrix %*% t(feature_matrix) %>% tril() %>% as.matrix()
#>       text1 text2 text3
#> text1     3     0     0
#> text2     1     3     0
#> text3     2     0     3
```

Answer (score 1):

There is always a way. the least elegant solution is probably two nested for-loops. Not elegant, but easy to read. Not very fast, though.

```
all <- numeric(0)
a <- c('tom','john','phil')  
b <- c('phil','leo','james')  
d <- c('tom','john', 'dan')
for(v1 in list(a, b, d))
  for(v2 in list(a, b, d)) {
    all <- c(all, sum((v1) %in% (v2)))
    print(v2)
  }
dim(all) <- rep(3, 2)
all[upper.tri(all)] <- NA
```